# Как в python выполнять команды linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, консоль, subprocess

Сейчас занимаюсь приложением, которое будет выполнять команды терминала linux. Столкнулся с проблемой, что результаты выполнения команд не сохраняются или команды просто не работают.

Используя **subprocess** столкнулся с тем, что оно не выполняет команды *cd*. Сразу вылетает exception

import subprocess

```
while True:
    command = input("Введите команду -> ")
    with subprocess.Popen(command, encoding="utf-8", stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
        print(proc.stdout.read())
```

Ошибка такая:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd'
```

Я понимаю, что можно использовать параметр cwd, который будет команду выполнять в определенной директории. Но мне кажется, что такой параметр не подходит. Он будет неудобен. (Может быть я не прав. Если я не прав, то прошу прислать ответ.)

Используя **os** столкнулся с проблемой того, что результат выполненной команды не учитывается. Пример:

```
import os

output = ''
while True:
    command = input("Введите команду -> ")
    os.system(command)
```

Выполняю команду *ls*:

```
Введите команду -> ls
crypt.py
DBClient.py
functions.py
```

Выполняю команду *cd*:
(результата нет, так как это просто переход)

После *cd* выполняю команду *ls*:

```
Введите команду -> ls
crypt.py
DBClient.py
functions.py
```

А мне нужно, чтобы прошлая команда учитывалась. То есть вывелось бы содержимое корневой директории (не проекта, а /home/*учетка*  ). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно запустить shell (bash например) в subprocess.Popen ,  оставить его открытым и передавать команды через пайп, читать ответ через второй пайп.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, написать пример?